# How to hide/show label when item is selected /not selected in mvvm?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have three labels in the same space bound to pickers from different pages.

What I would like to do is, when picker 1 has a selected item, make sure that *label 1* is visible and hide *label 2* and 3 when there is no selected item from picker 2 and 3.

Any help will be appreciated.

Page one

```
 <Picker SelectedItem="{Binding PICKER1}"  WidthRequest="120" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
      <Picker.Items>
           <x:String>15 cm</x:String>
           <x:String>30 cm</x:String>
           <x:String>45 cm</x:String>
      </Picker.Items>
 </Picker>
```

Page 2

```
 <Picker SelectedItem="{Binding PICKER2}"  WidthRequest="120" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
      <Picker.Items>
           <x:String>hello</x:String>
           <x:String>hi</x:String>
           <x:String>ciao</x:String>
       </Picker.Items>
 </Picker>
```

Page 3

```
 <Picker SelectedItem="{Binding PICKER3}"  WidthRequest="120" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
       <Picker.Items>
           <x:String>when</x:String>
           <x:String>how</x:String>
      </Picker.Items>
 </Picker>
```

Page 4

```
 <Label x:Name="lab11" Text="{Binding DisplayPICKER1}"  Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
 <Label x:Name="lab2" Text="{Binding DisplayPICKER2}"  Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
 <Label x:Name="lab3" Text="{Binding DisplayPICKER3}"  Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
```

Mainviewmodel

```
 string picker1 = string.Empty;
 public string PICKER1
 {
      get => picker1;
      set
      {
           if (picker1 == value)
                return;
           else
           {
               picker1 = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PICKER1));
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayPICKER1));
           }
      }
 }
 public string DisplayPICKER1 => $"distance: {PICKER1}";


 string picker2 = string.Empty;
 public string PICKER2
 {
      get => picker2;
      set
      {
           if (picker2 == value)
                return;
           else
           {
                picker2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PICKER2));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayPICKER2));
           }
      }
 }
 public string DisplayPICKER2 => $"Greet: {PICKER2}";


 string picker3 = string.Empty;
 public string PICKER3
 {
      get => picker3;
      set
      {
           if (picker3 == value)
                return;
           else
           {
                picker3 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PICKER3));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayPICKER3));
           }
      }
 }
 public string DisplayPICKER3 => $"{PICKER3}";
```

Comment: where are you stuck?  You should be able tot bind the IsVisible property of the label to a bool in your VM, and then update that bool as your picker values change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming properties `Picker1`, `Picker2`, and `Picker3` are selected and unselected as expected; e.g. `Label1` below will not be visible if both `Picker1` and `Picker2` are selected:

Use `Label` `IsVisible` property, define a [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding#define-a-imultivalueconverter), and use it with [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding#consume-a-imultivalueconverter):

```
<ContentPage 
  ...
  xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Converters">

<ContentPage.Resources>
  <converters:AllTrueMultiConverter x:Key="AllTrueMultiConverter"/>
  <converters:IsSelectedConverter x:Key="IsSelectedConverter"/>
  <converters:NotSelectedConverter x:Key="NotSelectedConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
  ...
  <Label Text="Label1 MultiBinding">
    <Label.IsVisible>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AllTrueMultiConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Picker1" Converter="{StaticResource IsSelectedConverter}" />
        <Binding Path="Picker2" Converter="{StaticResource NotSelectedConverter}" />
        <Binding Path="Picker3" Converter="{StaticResource NotSelectedConverter}" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </Label.IsVisible>
  </Label>
```

For `AllTrueMultiConverter` see [Define a IMultiValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding#define-a-imultivalueconverter)

Sample `IsSelectedConverter` and `NotSelectedConverter`:

```
namespace Converters
{
  public class IsSelectedConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value != null);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
  }
  ...
  public class NotSelectedConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == null);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

If `Label1` should be visible depending only on `Picker1` a `Binding` might be used:

```
<Label Text="Label1 Binding" IsVisible="{Binding Picker1, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedConverter}}"/>
```